# VaadinSession does not own lock during destruction leading to AssertionError

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, vaadin

We are running Vaadin (version 8.5.1, `vaadin-spring` version 3.1) and Spring (version 5.1.1) inside an embedded Tomcat. When I shutdown the Tomcat server I run into an AssertionError with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.setAttribute(VaadinSession.java:1108) ~[vaadin-server-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1]
at com.vaadin.spring.internal.UIScopeImpl$UIStore.destroy(UIScopeImpl.java:246) ~[vaadin-spring-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at com.vaadin.spring.internal.UIScopeImpl$UIStore.serviceDestroy(UIScopeImpl.java:260) ~[vaadin-spring-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.lambda$destroy$4(VaadinService.java:2115) ~[vaadin-server-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1]
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4649) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.forEach(Collections.java:5476) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.destroy(VaadinService.java:2115) ~[vaadin-server-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1]
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.destroy(VaadinServlet.java:1440) ~[vaadin-server-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1281) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
```

It seems like Tomcat's calls the destory() method of VaadinServlet which in turn calls VaadinService.destroy(). Because this will call VaadinSession.setAttribute it requires a lock which it does not own. Using the debugger I confirmed that the lock is not owned by anyone at this point in time.

What am I doing wrong? I searched online, but nobody seems to have the same problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in `vaadin-spring`. I created https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/383 for tracking this case.